# Quantificando valores negativos em um array

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um exercício, porém não foi da maneira como a plataforma queria, estou sem ideias de como resolver, estou no meu primeiro dia de javascript.... Segue o enunciado, o erro e minha tentativa.

> Uma empresa mandou uma lista contendo os números mensais de tudo o que
> ela faturou, e nosso trabalho é ajudá-los a criar um relatório que
> exiba em quantos meses eles tiveram o saldo negativo.
>
> `var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]`
>
> Com base no array acima, que está disponível no código, faça um loop
> que verifique quantos meses tiveram valores negativos e armazene a
> contagem uma variável chamada totalNegativos que também está
> disponível no código.

---

No Código tem isso ja escrito

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]

var totalNegativos = 0


//minha tentativa 

for ( var i = 0;  i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){
    numeros = listaDeGanhos[i]
    if ( numeros < 0 ){
        console.log(totalNegativos++) 
    }

}
```

Erro que recebo : Você deve verificar se o valor atual do array é negativo com um if

Comment: Seria possível ser mais claro quanto ao problema? O seu código está funcionando corretamente. Se o problema é em relação à impressão, basta colocar o operador `++` antes da variável. Dessa forma o incremento acontecerá antes de imprimir o valor.

Comment: Difícil dizer o que está errado, pois parece que o problema é no algoritmo que está analisando a lógica do seu código. Eu deduziria que ele não está conseguindo interpretar essa indireção que você criou com a variável `numeros`, ele deve estar esperando que no `if` você utilize `if (listaDeGanhos[i] < 0)`, mas isso é só um palpite, pois não tem como reproduzir o seu problema.

Comment: @user140828 era exatamente isso, o algoritmo da plataforma que estou utilizando nao reconheceu a variavel numeros. Fiz como você indicou e funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Passa aí como ficou seu código por favor! estou tentando seguir a sua estrutura modificando aqui mas não está retornando corretamente. Segue o código:

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
```

var totalNegativos = 0

//seu loop aqui:
for(var i = 0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){
totalNegativos = listaDeGanhos[i]
if(listaDeGanhos[i] < 0){
console.log(totalNegativos++)
}

}

```js
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
var totalNegativos = 0

//seu loop aqui:
for(var i = 0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){ 
    totalNegativos = listaDeGanhos[i]  
if(listaDeGanhos[i] < 0){
   console.log(totalNegativos++)
}

}
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mas já consegui realizar da maneira que a plataforma exigia, e foi exatamente como você sugeriu

Comment: Exite um erro nesta declaração aqui: `totalNegativos = listaDeGanhos[i]`, ela está alterando um valor que não deveria mudar neste momento. Só quando o valor fosse negativo

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias soluções possíveis, se o enunciado pede apenas a quantidade de números negativos, a solução abaixo é simples e faz o que se pede, sem exibir um console com o número que é negativo.

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
var totalNegativos = 0

//seu loop aqui:
for(var i = 0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){ 
    if(listaDeGanhos[i] < 0)
     totalNegativos++
} 
console.log(totalNegativos);
```

agora a solução mais bonita seria esta, mas que talvez o analisador de códigos não aceite:

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40];

const negativos = listaDeGanhos.filter(number => number < 0 );

console.log(negativos.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]

let totalNegativos = 0

listaDeGanhos.forEach(function (valor) {

    if(valor < 0){
        totalNegativos++
    }
})

console.log(totalNegativos) // 3
```

Agora se a plataforma exige realmente desta forma

```js
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]

var totalNegativos = 0

for ( var i = 0;  i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){

    if ( listaDeGanhos[i] < 0 ){
        totalNegativos++ // Acrescentando no total
        console.log(listaDeGanhos[i]) // Mostrando quanto foi
    }
}

// Mostre após o loop
console.log(totalNegativos)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
var totalNegativos = 0

for (var i = 0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){
  if(listaDeGanhos[i] < 0){
    totalNegativos ++; 
  }
 
}
console.log(totalNegativos)
```

Answer (score -1):

para mim, funcionou assim:

var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
var totalNegativos = 0

for (i = 0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++) {

console.log // aqui eu mandei apenas correr a contagem sem somar para validar a array
if (listaDeGanhos[i] < 0) {
console.log(totalNegativos++)  //o if valida os negativos e soma

}

}

Answer (score -2):

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
var totalNegativos = 0
for ( var i = 0;  i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){
        if ( listaDeGanhos[i] < 0 )
        totalNegativos++
    }
```

Comment: Estou fazendo o mesmo exercício, deve ser na mesma plataforma, e o código que aceitou foi esse, se colocar console.log... dará erro